# Send the API Headers in Rest Assured using java

Tags: java, rest-assured

API Headers have two parameter Content-Type=application/json and also accesstoken = "some_token"
I trying to automate the API using Rest assured but not successful.
Below is the code

```java
RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("serviceurl1");

//2. define the http request:
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given()  
                .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter());

JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
requestParams.put("longitude", eLongitude);
requestParams.put("latitude", eLaititude);
requestParams.put("country", eCity);

httpRequest.headers("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpRequest.headers("accesstoken", "some_token.");
httpRequest.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
System.out.println("the status code is: "+ statusCode);

Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, TestUtil.RESPONSE_CODE_200);

System.out.println("the status line is: "+ response.getStatusLine());

//6. get the headers:
Headers headers = response.getHeaders();
System.out.println(headers);

String contentType = response.getHeader("Content-Type");
System.out.println("the value of content-type header is: "+ contentType);

String contentLength = response.getHeader("Content-Length");
System.out.println("the value of Content-Length header is: "+ contentLength);
```

Getting error message as "Provide Application Token" and 404 error code display.

Comment: did you try this with postman if yes, can you plzz tell what is the key you are sending for token.

Comment: Its working in postman, In Header we are passing "accesstoken"="something" along with ContentType.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of postman how your are passing headers it would give clear picture

Comment: It is done, its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Your `httpRequest.headers("accesstoken", "kggkgkgkgketdfgxgcccvcdftfty.");` is wrong. It should be:

```
 httpRequest.headers("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
```

Comment: Private String token="kggkgkgkgketdfgxgcccvcdftfty.";   we have to send token like this.

Comment: Still getting error message as "alert": [{"message": "Provide Application Token", "type": "failure",

Comment: can u try "Bearer kggkgkgkgketdfgxgcccvcdftfty"

Answer (score 0):

can you try this once

`Response resp = given().when().contentType(ContentType.JSON).header("accesstoken", "token").body(body).put("url");`

You can pass the HashMap as body

Answer (score 0):

These are the issues I can think of

1. This might be an internal API and it is expecting "Provide Application Token" and not the "accesstoken"
2. The error code you are getting is 404. So either the service is down or the URL you are using is not correct.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Its working now the correct code is        :-------------RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
  httpRequest.headers("Content-Type", "application/json");
  httpRequest.headers("accesstoken", "something")

Comment: What was the issue here @VipinSingh